# Session GetLastAccessTime Returns 0 on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I am using Google App Engine \ Java and am trying to get the last time the user made a request , or in short use the method HttpSession.getLastAccessTime().
My code is straightforward :

```
log.write("SessionId:"+session.getId()+"LastAccessed:"+session.getLastAccessedTime()+"Creation:"+date.toString());
```

When checking the log the result of that line of code is 
SessionId:gckoLPCQZaH9sTiH2SRf6g***LastAccessed:0***Creation:Thu Feb 23 12:15:37 UTC 2012

I always get back zero ! The session is ok as you can see - it has an ID , a creation time etc , only the lastAccessTime is 0 when it shouldn't be .

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening ?

Comment: Do you have sessions enabled in you GAE config by having `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` in you `appengine-web.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no "Add comment" link on my web page, so I post an answer instead, even though this is a clarification question....

Where/when in your code do you call your `log.write(...)` line?

Comment: Hey Ian , you're probably asking if it could be that no request since session creation was made , hence getLastAccessTime would be 0 . It is very very unlikely but since I'm starting to go insane I'm looking into all options..